# In Google Sheets, how do you control the colour display of formula text so it appears as it would in the formula bar as opposed to being generic text?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have built a tutorial for Google Sheets and in the answers section where I'm displaying formulas as text, I'm having random inconsistency in how they are being displayed (see image).

I'm writing in the formula and then using apostrophe to show the formula text instead of the outcome, e.g.

```
'=IF(G3 > 0, "Yes", "No")
```

In some cells it formats it in all black default text, whereas in others it highlights the ranges with various colours, then turns anything in quotation marks green and numbers blue like it would in the formula bar.

Is there a way to control this formatting? The solutions become quite complex later on and so the formatting would improve accessibility.

[image]

Comment: Can you either share a sheet where this is happening, or show steps to reproduce the issue when creating a new sheet?